# How to access the attributes of the joined tables in yii2

Tags: join, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have two models(User, ReferralsForm) joined together in my controller. The join works fine but I am having a problem in accessing the attributes in ReferralsForm. Here's the code in my controller:

```
public function actionReferrals()
{
    $idOfCurrentUser = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $query = User::find()->joinWith('referrals')->where(['userid' => $idOfCurrentUser])->all();

    $model = new User();
    $ref_hash = $model->getHash();

    return $this->render('referrals' ,['query' => $query, 'ref_hash' => $ref_hash]);
}
```

My view:

```
        (...)
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <tbody><tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Referred Username</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <?php foreach ($query as $result){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $result->user_id?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result->display_name?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result->status?></td>
              <?php } ?>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        (...)
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\User::status
```

I wanted to access the `status` from ReferrasForm however it doesn't include the attributes from ReferralsForm, only the attributes from the Users even if I already joined them and added the `all()` from similar problems i read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relationName->attributeName`

```
 <td> <?= $result->referrals->status ?> </td>
```

If you have `hasMany()` relation then you need to loop through `$result->referrals` or use `$result->referrals[0]->status`

Comment: It was the `[0]` that I needed. Thank you